# Firebase onComplete causes crashes on quick exit

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am very new to android development. I am developing an app an on backend I am using firebase firestore as the databse.
**I have attached on complete listner like this,**

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("Students")
        .document(userID)
        .collection("Classes")
        .get(sourceL)
        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){

                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                    classList.add(document.getString("TeacherName"));
                    double val = document.getDouble("TeacherID");
                    int intVal = (int) val;
                    tIDList.add(intVal);
                }
                editor.putBoolean("TutionBase", false).apply();
                triggrtListView();

            } else {

                msgTXT.setText("Connection Issue");
                btnTXT.setText("Dismiss");
                retry.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    dialogretry.dismiss();
                    requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                });
                dialogretry.setOnCancelListener(dialog -> {
                    dialogretry.dismiss();
                    requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                });
                dialogretry.show();
            }
        });
```

it's using on a fragment.
source is using to define SERVER OR CACHE.

**code Works without errors on normal scenarios. If user pop to backstack fragment quickly while this method is running, app crashes giving follow log errors,**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.mcqpanthiya, PID: 6199
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FragmentTutionBase{c5193a6} (a82d5330-61ff-415e-95eb-c6c3b0b9254d) not attached to an activity.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:928)
    at com.example.mcqpanthiya.FragmentTutionBase.lambda$triggrtListView$14$com-example-mcqpanthiya-FragmentTutionBase(FragmentTutionBase.java:363)
    at com.example.mcqpanthiya.FragmentTutionBase$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

If I flag user inputs and remove it after completion there is no issue.

**But I want to know how to avoid this app crash. I want to know what causes this crash in more detail.**

If the user waits for 2 or 3 seconds and then exits, there are also no crashes.

Comment: Its because the listener operation may take a while and in that period if the user exits the Fragment, it may not be attached to an activity, hence the call to `requireActivity()` is causing an issue. You could check if the fragment is attached via `isAdded` flag on Fragment before using `requireActivity()`. You could also move this Firestore logic to a Activity ViewModel and share that data to fragment via `activityViewModels()`.

Answer (score 0):

The crash happens because the listener code gets run later, whenever the firebase operation is complete, and if the user navigates away before that happens the fragment has been detached from the activity and the call to `requireActivity()` throws.

If you just want it to fail gracefully in that case instead of crashing, change your code from using [`requireActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#requireActivity()) (which throws if the activity is not attached) to using [`getActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) instead (which can return null in those cases) and check that it is not null before using it. For example:

```java
FragmentActivity a = getActivity();
if( a != null ) {
   a.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

If you don't want any of the listener code to run in the case where the user navigated away already, you could use this to do an early exit from the listener

```java
FragmentActivity a = getActivity();
if( a == null ) return;

// the rest of the listener code
```